# Build a Node Module via NPM for a different target

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, webpack

I want to include the [client library of the Dash cryptocurrency](https://github.com/dashevo/platform/tree/master/packages/wallet-lib) into a React Native application. The problem is that via `npm install` it builds for NodeJS, where it assumes the core modules that are simply not there in React Native. I have been told by the developers themselves that it can be built via a web build. It's [isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphic_JavaScript). How can this be achieved practically?